# The entity type [classname] is not part of the model for the current context - on AppHarbor

Tags: entity-framework, appharbor

I had the error "The entity type [classname] is not part of the model for the current context" locally and on AppHarbor. I fixed it locally, pushed to git and AppHarbor pulled the new version but I cannot shift this error.

I tried deleting the class it's having trouble with, redeployed and it worked on AH.

I then re-created the db table, brought it into EF, regenerated everything: it works fine locally but not on AH. I am totally stumped.

Edit: Just deployed to a brand new AH application and the error persists. Published to local file system and opened with IIS and it's fine. Hmnn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!

I had been lazy with my connection strings. One pointed to an AppHarbor db and the other to a local SSExpress.

Rather than comment out or delete the connection string that pointed to my local db I had just renamed it by appending an _old, so I had

connection 1 to AH- name="MyAppContext

connection 2 to Local - name="MyAppContext_old

Even though there are no references to MyAppContext_old other than in web.config, this connection seems to be explored and resulted in the error.

Solved. Hooray.